# How hide symbol in joomla paging?

Tags: joomla

How hide symbol in joomla paging ?

Example << Start < Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next > End >>
I want to delete << <>>> so result is Start Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next End

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like core hacks, you could create simple js script using mootools:

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
   $$('ul.pagenav a').each(function(el){
    var text = el.getFirst().get('html');
    text = text.replace('&lt;','');
    text = text.replace('&gt;','');
    text = text.replace('\u00AB','');
    text = text.replace('\u00BB','');
        el.getFirst().set('html',text);
    });
});
```